# Explain the C code instruction

Tags: c, microcontroller

The code below is used for programming microcontrollers. I want to know what the code below is doing. I know that '|' is OR and '&' AND but what is the whole line doing?

```
lcd_port = (((dat >> 4) & 0x0F)|LCD_EN|LCD_RS);
```

Comment: Without any further informations about what are `LCD_EN` and `LCD_RS`, it'll be difficult to answer.

Comment: Is this dealing with HD44780? Which microcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to put into context since we don't know what `dat` contains, but we can see that:

1. The data is right-shifted by 4 bits, so `11111111` becomes `00001111`, for instance.
2. That value is AND'ed with 0x0F. This is a common trick to remove unwanted bits, since `b & 1 = 1` and `b & 0 = 0`. Think of your number as a sequence of bits, here's a 2-byte example :

   0011010100111010

   &

   0000000000001111

   ---

   0000000000001010
3. Now the `LCD_EN` and `LCD_RS` flags are OR'ed. Again, this is a common binary trick, since `b | 1 = 1` and `b | 0 = b`, so you can add flag but not remove them. So, if say `LCD_EN = 0x01` and `LCD_RS = 0x02`,

   0000000000001010

   |

   0000000000000011

   ---

   0000000000001011

Hope that's clearer for you.

Comment: That would make sense since the AND mask is one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Some guesses, as you'll probably need to find chip datasheets to confirm this:-

`lcd_port` is probably a variable that directly maps to a piece of [memory-mapped hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) - likely an alphanumeric LCD display.

The display probably takes data as four-bit 'nibbles' (hence the shift/and operations) and the higher four bits of the port are control signals.

`LCD_EN` is probably an abbreviation for LCD ENABLE - a control line used on the port.

`LCD_RS` is probably an abbreviation for LCD READ STROBE (or LCD REGISTER SELECT) - another control line used on the port. Setting these bits while writing to the port probably tells the port the kind of operation to perform.

I wouldn't be at all surprised if the hardware in use was a [Hitachi HD44780](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller) or some derivative.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be setting some data and flags on the lcd_port. The first part applies the mask 0x0F to (dat >> 4) (shift dat right 4) which is followed by applying the LCD_EN flag and then LCD_RS flag.

Answer (score 0):

It is shifting the variable `data` four bits to the right, then masking the value with the value 15. This results in a value ranging from 0-15 (four left-most bits). This result is binary ORd with the `LCD_EN` and `LCD_RS` flags.

Answer (score 0):

This code is shifting the bits of dat 4 bits to the right and then using & 0x0F to ensure it gets only those 4 least significant bits.  It's then using OR to find which bits exist in that value OR LCD_EN OR LCD_RS and assigning that value to lcd_port.